# Clojure (require 'examples.introduction) returns FileNotFound exception

Tags: windows, clojure

Trying to do (require 'examples.introduction) from the Programming Clojure book on Windows 10. Getting a FileNotFound Exception.
(require 'clojure.lang.io) works as expected.

Unzipped the source and set my CLASSPATH as follows:

.;JAVA_HOME\lib;C:\Users\easte\shcloj3-code\code\src\examples

Using the Leiningen repl.

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance,
Slavko

Answer (score 3):

Your classpath entry should point at the directory above all of the namespaces, not inside a namespace itself. So it should end with `src`, not `src\examples`.